# Ambient isotopy on closed unit ball

Tags: algebraic-topology

Consider a point $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$. $F(x,t)=x-ta$ is an ambient isotopy from $\{a\}$ to $\{0\}$. By the homeomorphism $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow B^n:f(x)=\frac{x}{1+\parallel x\parallel}$ (where $B^n$ is the unit open ball), we can extend the $F$ to an ambient isotopy $G:D^n\times [0,1]\rightarrow D^n$ taking $\{f(a)\}$ to $0$, relative to $S^{n-1}$, where $D^n$ is the closed unit ball and $S^{n-1}$ is the sphere.

I define $G$ as $G(x,t)=f(f^{-1}(x)-ta)$ $\forall x\in B^n,t\in[0,1]$, and $G(x,t)=x$ $\forall x\in S^{n-1}$. But now I have the problem proving this $G$ is continuous.

Any hint please?

Comment: In order to apply the pasting lemma you need to know that $f(f^{-1}(x)-ta)$ extends to $S^{n-1}$ and moreover that the extension is the identity on $S^{n-1}$. So you need to show that whenever $(x_n,t_n)\in B^n\times [0,1]$ is a sequence convergent to some element in $(x,t)\in S^{n-1}\times[0,1]$ then $G(x_n,t_n)\to G(x,t)=x$. Which doesn't seem to be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us first observe that $f^{-1} : B^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is given by $f^{-1}(x)  = \frac{x}{1-\lVert x \rVert}$.

$G$ is continuous on the open set $B^n \times I$ and on the closed set $S^{n-1} \times I$. Thus it remains to show that if $(x_n,t_n)$ is a sequence in $B^n \times I$ which converges to $(x,t) \in S^{n-1} \times I$ (i.e. $x_n \to x$ and $t_n \to t$), then $G(x_n,t_n) \to G(x,t) = x$. W.l.o.g. we may assume that all $x_n \ne 0$.

Let $r_n = \lVert x_n \rVert$. Thus $r_n \to 1$ and $x_n - (1-r_n)t_na \to x$. We have
$$f^{-1}(x_n) - t_na = \frac{x_n}{1-r_n} - t_na = \frac{x_n - (1-r_n)t_na}{1-r_n} ,$$
$$G(x_n,t_n) = \frac{x_n - (1-r_n)t_na}{1-r_n} / \left(1 + \left\lVert \frac{x_n - (1- r_n)t_na}{1-r_n} \right\rVert \right) = \frac{x_n - (1-r_n)t_na}{1- r_n + \lVert x_n - (1-r_n)t_na \rVert} \to \frac{x}{0 + \lVert x \rVert} = x $$